# Why BIOS is not asking for HDD password on reboot but only after power off?

Tags: bios

I was reading about BIOS and I saw this:

> Next, BIOS will begin checking memory at 0000:0472h. This address contains a flag which will tell the BIOS if the system is booting from a cold boot or warm boot.

As you can see, it tells that the BIOS has 2 types to check the booting process. It says when the BIOS finds a warm boot (value 1234h) it will skip the POST routines remaining, however if the BIOS finds a cold boot, the remaining POST routines will be run.

Now, supposing that I have a password in the startup (user password set in the BIOS) of the system and a hard disk.

When I power up the computer, this means that the BIOS will read for a cold boot and will run the remaining POST routines, and of course will ask for the user's and hard disk's password. But when I reboot the system from the operating system (in this case, a Linux distribution), why doesn't the BIOS requests for the hard disk's password? Does this means that the BIOS is reading now a warm boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quote is about the old legacy BIOS (16-bit). Nowadays most BIOSes implement [UEFI](http://www.uefi.org/)-compliant firmware, which works in a pretty different way. The [Opal specification](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_Storage_ReferenceDocument_Opal_Integration_Guidelines_v1.00_r1.14_publicreview.pdf) published by TCG, describes how the UEFI firmware interacts with self-encrypting harddrives.
However, it seems your scenario is not really BIOS-related. According to [ArchLinux wiki on the topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Self-Encrypting_Drives) :

> Typical self-encrypting drives, once unlocked, will **remain unlocked
>   as long as power is provided**. This vulnerability can be exploited by
>   means of altering the environment external to the drive, without
>   cutting power, in effect keeping the drive in an unlocked state. For
>   example, it has been shown (by researchers at Universiy of
>   Erlangen-Nuremberg) that it is possible to reboot the computer into an
>   attacker-controlled operating system without cutting power to the
>   drive. The researchers have also demonstrated moving the drive to
>   another computer without cutting power

So it's probably the drive itself, and not the BIOS/firmware, which is caching the password on warm reboot.

Other references:

- [UEFI Plugfest: Strategies for Firmware Support of Self-Encrypting Drives](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Plugfest_JBOBZIN_2012Q1_V2.pdf)
- EDK2's [SecurityPkg](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/SecurityPkg) implements various Opal-related functionality, e.g. [1](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/SecurityPkg/Tcg/Opal), [2](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/SecurityPkg/Library/OpalPasswordSupportLib)